# Threading behavior is weird in python subprocess

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

So I essentially have a case like this where in my main script I have

```
command = 'blender -b ' + settings.BLENDER_ROOT + 'uploadedFileCheck.blend -P ' + settings.BLENDER_ROOT + 'uploadedFileCheck.py -noaudio'
process = Popen(command.split(' ') ,stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()
```

And in the subprocess script **uploadedFileCheck.py** I have the line

```
exportFile(fileIn, fileOut)
Thread(target=myfunction).start()
```

So I expect the subprocess to be finished, or at least to return to out, err after the *exportFile()* call, but it seems it's waiting for the Thread to finish as well. Does anyone understand this behavior?

Also, in case you're wondering, I'm calling that other python file as a subprocess because the main script is in python2 and that script (blender) is in python3, but that's irrelevant (and can't change)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A process won't exit until all its non-daemon threads have exited. By default, `Thread` objects in Python are created as non-daemon threads. If you want your script to exit as soon as the main thread is done, rather than waiting for the spawned thread to finish, set the [`daemon`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) flag on the `Thread` object to `True` prior to starting it:

```
t = Thread(target=myfunction)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```

Note that this will kill the daemon thread in a non-graceful way, without any cleanup occuring. If you're doing any kind of work in that thread that needs to be cleaned up, you should consider an approach where you signal the thread to shut itself down, instead.

Comment: Apparently OP wants the opposite of what you're recommending: `it seems it's waiting for the Thread to finish`, at least that's what I understood from the question...

Comment: @jadkik94 Hmm, I took that to mean that he's wants it to *not* wait for the `Thread` to finish...I guess we'll let the OP clarify and go from there.

Comment: @dano You've got it right! I DON'T want to wait for the thread to finish before the subprocess exits. Although that seems to be causing it's own problems. In this situation, what happens to the resources in the subprocess (ones that the thread might use) when the subprocess exits before the thread is complete?

Comment: @user1561753 A thread can't live beyond the life of the process it's running inside. So when `uploadedFileCheck.py` exits, the thread running `myFunction` will immediately end, too. Do you want the operation happening inside `myFunction` to continue to run beyond the life of `uploadedFileCheck.py`? If so, you can't use a thread for that. You would have to use `subprocess.Popen` to launch whatever `myFunction` is doing as a separate script.

Comment: Thanks! That pretty much answers everything I needed to know